# TinyButStrong gives an corrupt DOCX file

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong, php-7.4

I'm using TinyButStrong (with opentbs plugin) to merge an DOCX (XLSX/ODT/ODS) file with CSV data (file upload).
On my Linux pc with libre-/openoffice the produced merged DOCX file gives an error:
"SAXException: [word/document.xml line 2]: Couldn't find end of Start Tag blip"

On my client's pc with windows and microsucks Word it also gives an error but can't continue (opens a blank file).

I'm using PHP7.3 and the latest TBS and OpenTBS plugin.
It has worked before, but after updating either PHP or other server software it started malfunctioning. (don't know exactly when as I'm dependent of my client's feedback).

I don't see any error inside the apache error/access log (in debug mode),
I have created a custom log for this script, and the complete script is executed (up until the merged output file and beyond when it inserts data into a database).
I have enabled the TBS error output but that also doesn't show any error's.

The source document DOCX has no error's when i open it in Libreoffice, only after the merge the error exists. if i then open the merged document (in Libreoffece and scip the error) it is displayed correct, and i can save it ones more. than i can open it without error's in both libreoffice and microsoft office.

> - Debug command: OPENTBS_DEBUG_XML_SHOW
> - OpenTBS version: 1.10.0
> - TinyButStrong version: 3.11.0
> - PHP version: 7.3.15-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1YES
> - Opened document: /tmp/phpgYoneg
> - Activated features for document type: openxml/docx
> - Deleted files in the archive: none
> - Added files in the archive:
>
>   - word/media/opentbs_added_1.png
>   - word/media/opentbs_added_2.png
>   - word/media/opentbs_added_3.png
> - Modified files in the archive:
>
>   - docProps/core.xml
>   - word/document.xml
>   - [Content_Types].xml
>   - word/_rels/document.xml.rels

EDIT:
Apparently changing a picture with field:

```
[data.image;ope=changepic;adjust=sameheight]
```

and `array $data['image'] = '';`
doesn't work.

don't yet know how to proceed from here, how to stop TinyButStrong to change it when the input is empty?

So I'm kind of out of ideas, has anybody a suggestion how to find and/or fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the erroneous merged DOCX ? Or a snippet to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Narrowed it to a pic with an error (the r:embed has no second quote):
<pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed="rId2&quot;></a:blip><a:stretch><a:fillRect/></a:stretch></pic:blipFill>